# Drawing chamber or container in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to make the following diagram. I know the basics of tikz but here I'm struggling. Can you advise me how to make the container with seedlings? Thanks for your help.

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are "too localized". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you **only** want to know how to make the *container* with TikZ, or what I understand by the container, this is a first solution. Please give more details for your question: do you want to know how to make the container or all the table?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand*{\seed}[1]{% #1 is the center
($#1-(0,.4)$) -- +(0,.8) ($#1+(-.22,0)$) -- +(.44,0) ($#1 +(-.15,.22)$) -- +(.3,0)    ($#1+(-.15,-.22)$) -- +(.3,0)
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]

\foreach \x/\y [count=\i] in {0/0,0/-.5,-.8/-.5,-.8/-3,1.8/-3,1.8/-.5,1/-.5,1/0}{
\coordinate (p\i) at (\x,\y);}

\draw (p1) \foreach \i in {2,...,8}{
-- (p\i)};

\foreach \x/\y in {0/-1.2,0/-2.2,1/-1.2,1/-2.2}{
\draw[scale around={.7:(\x,\y)}] \seed{(\x,\y)};
};

\node[above] at (.5,0) {\LARGE $P_1$};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Please check if the figure obtained match with you request, I just reproduced what I saw.

[image]

The other containers can be obtained using `\begin{scope}[shift={(x,0)}] ... \end{scope}` with the code shown above inside it, considering x as the horizontal space you want. The arrows and other texts is just "play" with the coordinates and nodes.

Comment: The arrows could be done with `\tikzmark`, which would be much better than trying to guess and tweak the coordinates.

Comment: @MYaseen208 You are welcome! I will assume then that my interpretation of your question and the image that you showed was right. :-)